# Problems with replacing into string

Tags: ruby, gsub

I'm trying to execute code like this:

```
template = "
... here html tags
[sitename]
... here html tags
"

template = template.gsub(/\[sitename\]/,"http://google.com")
```

But it's not working. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Can you describe how it's not working?

In ruby 1.9.2 I get what I expected, the command

```
puts template
```

gives

```
... here html tags
http://google.com
... here html tags
```